# how to resolve weak symbols at link time (not load time) inside a shared library

Tags: linux, g++, shared-libraries

I've had another accident of a shared library finding some symbols somewhere else 
than inside itself.
How can I prevent this?
I'm already using -fvisibility=hidden.
It looks like that all template functions are compiled as weak symbols and only resolved at load time.
I'm already using RTLD_DEEPBIND to avoid this problem -- but purify ignores this option.

Comment: other than regarding purify not supporting this option and causing crazy errors, this is also a problem because of the shared library is getting too big and the resulting symbols are called via thunks.

Comment: Also I'm interested in being able to control, where which symbol finally ends up and who will be using it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution to this problem is the objcopy command from GNU binutils.
It allows one to change symbol attributes.
The option to use would potentially be
--localize-symbols=filename
or
--globalize-symbols=filename
Another way is to use the g++ compiler option -fno-weak -- but the g++ man page discourages the use of this option -- I'm not certain why -- potentially certain symbols from the C++ library must end up as weak.